# How to show Virtuemart Product Type Parameters in a Table Format

Tags: joomla1.5, virtuemart

Would you please kindly tell me Instead of showing Product Description how to show Virtuemart Product Type Parameters in a Table Format in the fly page, just like in the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is- You have to go to components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/product_details/  and then open up - flypage.tpl.php. This is the page which basically loads when a user sees a particular product under a category. If you do not want to show the product description then just remove the description area from the fly page and then design the page with CSS just like the way you want. In case you want to show the product type parameters as product specification you may need to change some codes here - administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/ps_product_type.php around line 553 to 580.

Thanks :)